# Unable to retrieve the link & click it- Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to take all the weblinks of the webpage in an array & i want to click on the link with the text match as the position of the url link in the webpage is not fixed.
My below code fails with an error:

Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 15, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .entity.element.a)

```
var result_links =element.all(by.css('.entity.element.a'));  
    for (var i=0;i<22;i++){
        result_links.get(i).getText().then(function(text){
        console.log("The fetched links are "+text);
        if (text==="Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345"){
            result_links.get(i).click();
        }       
        })
    }
```

I tried to used result_links.length property of Javascript but strangely i do not get the array number in it so thats the reason i had to statically assign number 22 as the weblink i am looking for will always be between 0-22

The output of the below code is:

```
The fetched links are Stick urls
The fetched links are Budgets 27167678
The fetched links are www.xyztyi.com
The fetched links are YT its yours
The fetched links are wwww.thytghj.com
The fetched links are Engage stick
The fetched links are Methods 156788.com
The fetched links are Stithgyuji 287878
The fetched links are Hello 679u
The fetched links are Johns 766788
The fetched links are www.gtyyuuhjhj
The fetched links are yuyuuyukuku
The fetched links are Stanfods 777686y88
The fetched links are www.xyz.com
The fetched links are Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If its not mandatory to go for the array approach then as suggested above you can use linktext or partiallinktext, it should work.
Alternatively you can also try indexOf method i.e

```
var result_links =element.all(by.css('.entity.element.a'));  
    for (var i=0;i<22;i++){
        result_links.get(i).getText().then(function(text){
        console.log("The fetched links are "+text);
        var index=text.indexOf("Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345");
        result_links.get(index).click();       
        })
    }
```

Comment: The above code will not work. You need to change `result_links.get(i).getText()` to `result_links.getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `by.css()`, you can use `by.linktext("Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345")` or `by.partialLinkText("Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345")` or `by.cssContainingText(".entity.element.a","Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345")`

**Other alternative solutions:**

```
var result_links =element.all(by.css('.entity.element.a')); 
result_links.getText().then(function(linkList){
    var index=text.indexOf("Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345");
    result_links.get(index).click();  
});
```

or

```
var result_links =element.all(by.css('.entity.element.a')); 
result_links.filter(function(link){
  return link.getText().then(function(linkText){
       return linkText == "Xtreme Testing -explorers 12345";
  });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: This helps but what was the problem in my approach ? is it the if condition ?

Comment: You cannot use the variable `i` used in for loop inside getText() promise because of javascript's asynchronous behavior. So you have to implement closure to access the value of variable `i` inside `getText()` promise.